# ColdFusion WDDX conversion doesn't work with ColdFusion images?

Tags: coldfusion, wddx

I'm trying to create a CFML to WDDX packet as part of a caching mechanism. I get a cfwddx error related to a Java image variable when I attempt to pass in a coldfusion image as part of input. I can get the same error creating a new CF image and then passing that in as input.

```
  <cfwddx action="cfml2wddx" input="#aNewCFImage#" output="wddxConverted" />
```

Error Occurred While Processing Request
Error reading property for java.awt.color.ICC_ColorSpace.maxValue.

ColdFusion 8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to send it over as a binary file.

see: http://books.google.ca/books?id=sWjmIxqeBxMC&pg=PA730&lpg=PA730#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: Henry, I was really looking to store the stuff that's given in the dump, which is imageInfo() without using imageInfo. However, I guess there wouldn't be a problem including the entire image. I'll have to check.

Comment: I just said the heck with it and duplicated the struct and did an imageInfo() on the image.

Comment: then send over the struct returned from imageinfo(aNewCFImage) http://www.cfquickdocs.com/cf9/#imageinfo

Answer (score 0):

I'd convert the image to base64. That can be safely stored in a string.

Comment: Thanks ray. I wasn't so concerned with caching the actual image as I was caching the image properties and an array containing the top and left CSS properties of the sprites on the canvas. (which is a master canvas containing sprites). The image was written to the images directory so that it can be cached by the browser. I basically wanted to cache what I was seeing with the CFDUMP. However, the cfdump just displays the image info and ignores the image when you dump an image. That was my mistake.